# End of MFI ? Cable to arduino n others

Tags: arduino, programming, iphone

I am interested in the MFI made for iPod program, and found

This [$59 Cable Lets You Connect iPhone to Arduino — No Jailbreaking!](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2011/07/59-cable-lets-you-connect-iphone-to-arduino-no-jailbreaking.html)

[Programming iPhone Sensors Book](http://programmingiphonesensors.com/redpark/cable.html)

I have ordered the cable and will check it
But the question is how would this influence on my device working with that cable or a clone with out apple approval of MFI?

Is this apple response to android hardware dev openness?

Thanks a lot

Edit:
im interested in the software side, in the approval for the appstore, as the normal expensive approval for the MFI is not in my plans right now...

Comment: apple  !=  open. doing any hardware connection requires a significant dollar investment. Using someone else's hw, is an option, but expen$ive.

Comment: Yeah, Apple's pretty much the opposite of open, and doesn't show any signs of changing this.

Answer (score 3):

Straight from the [cable manufacturer's website](http://redpark.com/c2db9.html):

> The cable is used in conjunction with the Redpark Serial Cable SDK. Together these tools enable hobbyist, education and enterprise developers to write iOS apps that communicate with serial devices. These apps may be deployed for private use at home, at school or in an office. **Under current Apple policy this cable may not be used with apps sold on the App Store.**

From what I understand, Apple's MFI approval grants you the right to use the "Made For iPod" or "Made For iPhone" logos on your product, and you also get developer support from Apple.

These cables are already MFI approved and sold with a mark-up to indicate so.  Your choice in using this cable is solely up to you, just don't expect to be able to use any of Apple's trademarks when advertising your product (if you do intend to sell something eventually).  If this is for your own personal project/hacking, then anything goes.

There are some examples out there of people using the audio jack to send/receive data from their i-devices as well, which may be an interesting (and somewhat portable) alternative.